# php - i am getting logged out after being idle

Tags: session, php

I do not want the user to be logged out of the site even if the person is idle for, it is okay if the person is logged out if he has closed the browser.

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 180000
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 1
session.save_path      = "/var/lib/php/session"
cookie_lifetime        = 0
```

Is there any setting that i am missing?

Please help

To set the life time i have added the following code.

```
session_set_cookie_params(21600);
session_start();
```

Comment: use cookie and extend the expiration ...

Comment: Is "being idle" technically the same as "close browser"? Server hasn't seem a PHPSID for a given amount of time and abandon that SID.

Comment: @7-isnotbad i have added the session_set_cookie

Answer (score 1):

You need extend your live time of cookie, remember that session id is stored in user webbrowser within cookie, set `session.cookie_lifetime` with a more big value too.

Comment: I have added the session_set_cookie_params(21600);
    session_start();... i have updated my answer.. is there anything else that need to be added?

Comment: Set your **cookie_lifetime** value to a big number too (seconds that you need)

Comment: 21600 = 6 hours.. but i dont get it beyond 2 hours.

Comment: In your question I see **cookie_lifetime = 0**! You need change **0** to **21600** too

Answer (score 1):

```
session_set_cookie_params(21600);
session_start();
```

21600 seconds is only 6 hours

Try setting to something bigger maybe even `PHP_INT_MAX`

Answer (score 0):

Dont know whether it will help just wrote to give u the idea of how?....cookie are saved at user browser so ,

```
$cookieName = "userscookie";
$lifetime = time() + (60*60*24); // one day life
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName])) {  
    $value = $_COOKIE[$cookieName];
    // one day life from day of access
    setcookie($cookieName, $value, $lifetime);
} else {
    $value = "this value to store"; 
    setcookie($cookieName, $value, $lifetime);
}
```

**output:**

[image: the cookie got a life ....]

**Thankyou**